# Moving emails from Archived to Folders?

Tags: gmail

I have to sort through like 2,000++ emails that have been archived.  Is there a short cut to moving them into folders right from archived, then having to move them into mailbox and then move them into folders?

Comment: Gmail doesn't have folders, it has labels. It's not clear to me from your question just what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "All mail"
2. Click the checkmark and choose "All"
3. Above all your e-mail you will have a text similar to:
   "All 50 conversations on this page are selected. Select all 118,459 conversations in All Mail"
   Click on "Select all ***** conversations in All Mail"
4. Next to the button "Move to inbox" you have a label button. Click that and choose to what label/folder all your e-mails should be moved to.

Gmail have labels instead of folders. But they work kind of the same way. The only difference is that an email can be in multiple labels. If it was folders, it wouldn't be possible to have one email in multiple folders.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I did use the wrong term...folder instead of label...sory, I know there is a big difference.  But this should definitely help me.  Also,taking it one step further, is there a way to move the contents of these "labels" to a folder in my desktop?